# Why does react-hook-form consider the select field empty on submission?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-hook-form, yup

Can someone elucidate me as to why upon submission 'category' is considered empty and triggers the invalid call of react form hooks?

I simplified the code as much as possible but without stripping away the involved pieces that could be interacting with each other.

Thanks!

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';

const SelectRoot = styled.div`
    position: relative;
`;

export const SelectOriginal = styled.select`
    width: 100%;
`;

export function Select(props) {
  return (
    <SelectRoot>
      <SelectOriginal {...props} />
    </SelectRoot>
  );
}

const schema = yup
    .object({
        category: yup.string().required(),
    })
    .required();

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

  const onValidSubmit = async (data) => {
        console.log('valid: ', data)
  }

  const onInvalidSubmit = async (errors) => {
        console.log('invalid: ', errors)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onValidSubmit, onInvalidSubmit)}>
        <Select {...register('category')}>
          <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
        </Select>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is this warning, which you can probably see in your console:

```bash
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `App`.
    at Select
    at form
    at div
    at App
```

React Hook Form needs to have access to the `ref` of the `select` element, which you will need to pass explicitly when wrapping HTML elements in a custom React component, as passing the `ref` returned by the `register` method directly to the custom component won't work: `ref` is a reserved prop name in React.

```
const Select = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <SelectRoot ref={ref}>
      <SelectOriginal {...props} />
    </SelectRoot>
  )
})
```

Comment: Interesting. I found another workaround but was puzzled about the reason the above wasn't working. That makes total sense, and I feel kind of dumb for not looking at the result of _register_. Thank you!